# Changing WMS layer CRS/URI in a layout

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wms, qgis-print-layouts

My project uses a public WMS basemap to fill in data outside my ROI, with the WMS CRS chosen to be suitable given my project CRS.

Now I'm creating an (alternate) layout in my project which outputs in a different CRS (epsg:3857). Unsurprisingly, in this layout the WMS layer has visual artefacts due to reprojection, especially in labels.

Is there a way to change the WMS CRS for the layer to match the layout CRS **in that layout only**?

As far as I can tell, when I added the WMS layer, my choice of CRS then got hard-coded. I can manually change it by hacking the raster source URI, for instance to `crs=EPSG:3857&dpiMode=7&format=image/png&layers=Sub_regional&styles&url=http://maps.geogratis.gc.ca/wms/CBMT` (I changed the original `CRS=` to 3857) and then also setting the layer CRS in QGIS to match.

However, then it looks bad in my canvas in the project CRS, as the problem gets reversed. The WMS offers data in many CRSes, but no **one** individual one looks good (especially labels) when reprojected to **both** the project/canvas and layout CRS.

Before I go down some route of having 2 copies of the layer differing only in CRS and URI, one used in this one layout and one everywhere else -- and the resultant hassle of keeping their other layer settings in sync going forward -- is there a less klugey solution? One where QGIS would request the WMS data with a different CRS setting based on the context?

**In particular, since a layout can override so many map canvas/project rendering settings, can it modify the WMS CRS, or the layer URI specification more broadly?**

Comment: Since QGIS is well capable of on-the-fly reprojection, why would you try to force a specific CRS on a WMS-layer?

Comment: @Erik, QGIS reprojects the data it is given by the layer provider. So if the WMS server -- dutifully following the instructions in the URI  -- sends back data in EPSG:3978, for instance, QGIS then reprojects it in EPSG:3857 in the layout. This is great for feature symbology but warps and rotates the labels the WMS server burned into the raster in the layer's CRS.

Comment: does your WMS offer other projections? You can usually set the projection of the WMS when you add the layer.

Comment: @Ian, yes it does. But not one single projection that, after selection when adding the layer, would look good reprojected to both the project CRS and the layout CRS. In essence, since a layout can override so many map canvas/project rendering settings, I'm trying to find how it could override the layer URI specification or similar. (added this last sentence to the Q for clarity)

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do it with a single data source, duplication is the way to go.  I think  https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33928 is related.